# Отправить POST запрос на сайт в котором нет form

Tags: java, post

Хочу прикрутить к андроид приложению авторизацию на сайт https://wsp.kbtu.kz/#!LoginView/ . Но проблема состоит в том, что на сайте авторизация выполнена не через форму,а просто input и button. Как это можно реализовать на java?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: посмотрите в консоли хрома в момент нажатия на "Вход" какой запрос отправляется на сервер.И отправляйте такой же запрос.

Comment: В данном случае одним POST-запросом отделаться не получится. Интерфейс построен на фреймворке Vaadin. Все ваши действия транслируются в виде RPC на сервер. Т.е. на момент нажатия на кнопку "вход", серверу уже давно известно что вы ввели в поля пользователь и пароль, потому что клиент после каждого вашего действия(нажатия клавишы на клавиатуре или клик мышкой) уведомлял об этом сервер.

Comment: Что тогда нужно будет использовать в случае vaadin?

Comment: @Koki, смотря какую цель Вы преследуете.

Comment: @Koki, и какое отношение к этому сайту имеете.

Comment: @Koki, я бы для начала озаботился наличием на стороне сервера OAUTH аутентификации и веб-сервисов для нормальной работы, а не городил огород на имеющихся веб-формах.

Comment: Если коротко то это наш универский сайт с расписанием занятий и т.д. + у которого нет апи и он очень неудобный. Цель создать приложение под андроид и спарсить все нужные данные в удобном виде, но без авторизации данные взять не получится

Comment: Спарсить, как с обычного просто так тоже ничего с Ваадином не получится - весь интерфейс строится асинхронно.

Comment: если у вас есть доступ к разработке оригинального сайта, то вы сами можете написать это самое апи. А если Вы просто студент, который хочет расписание в мобильном телефоне, то остаётся только испытывать муки

Comment: ну можно еще относительно просто авторизоваться и извлечь данные с помощью какого-нибудь селениума.

Comment: в данном случае вы будете периодически заходить на данный сервис, извлекать данные, класть их в свою БД. написать своё АПИ. и в мобильном приложении получать данные уже из него